# How do I wait for a process started by Runtime.exec() to finish?

Tags: java, synchronization, runtime

I have the next code:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(args);
```

and I want my program to wait for the Runtime.getRuntime().exec(args); to finish cause it last 2-3sec and then to continue.

Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a sample code:

```
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(ANonJava.exe@);
InputStream in = proc.getInputStream();
byte buff[] = new byte[1024];
int cbRead;

try {
    while ((cbRead = in.read(buff)) != -1) {
        // Use the output of the process...
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    // Insert code to handle exceptions that occur
    // when reading the process output
}

// No more output was available from the process, so...

// Ensure that the process completes
try {
    proc.waitFor();
} catch (InterruptedException) {
    // Handle exception that could occur when waiting
    // for a spawned process to terminate
}

// Then examine the process exit code
if (proc.exitValue() == 1) {
    // Use the exit value...
}
```

You can find more on this site: http://docs.rinet.ru/JWP/ch14.htm

Comment: Yes,yours is working.Thanks!

and is it possible to sinchronize. If I dont want to use Runtime.getRuntime().exec(args) but 

WsImport.doMain(args);

Answer (score 8):

use [Process.waitFor()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor()):

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(args);
int status = p.waitFor();
```

From JavaDoc:

> causes the current thread to wait, if necessary, until the process represented by this Process object has terminated. This method returns immediately if the subprocess has already terminated. If the subprocess has not yet terminated, the calling thread will be blocked until the subprocess exits.

Comment: Worked beautifully. Thanks. Very similar to `awaitTermination()` used for Thread Pools.